# What is AttributeSet and what is it used for?

Tags: java, swing, interface

I have read the docs, but the docs seem vague to me and I'm having a hard time understanding what it is exactly and what it's used for.

Two question regarding this:

1. What exactly is the `AttributeSet` interface? What is the purpose of instances of
   classes implementing this interface?
2. Also, the `Style` interface is a subinterface of the `AttributeSet`
   interface. What exactly is this interface? What is the purpose of
   instances of classes implementing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `AttributeSet` implementation is supposed to hold a set of Key,Value pair objects.

You can use HashMap/HashTable etc for you own implementation of AttributeSet.

`AttributeSet` doesnt have any method for adding key values. There comes  `MutableAttributeSet`

```
Style
```

is a 
`MutableAttributeSet` which provides `Listener` support. Which means you can change the key-value based on some changeListener.

Comment: Can you give me an example of using Style or MutableAttributeSet in practice? For example when creating a word processor?

Comment: No. But maybe this link will help you http://programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet

Comment: Thanks for the link. By the way, if an `AttributeSet` implementation is meant to hold values of some kind, and a key to access them - why not just use a `HashMap`? Is it because there are a number of ways to implement this, and `AttributeSet` hides the way this key-value coupling is implemented? Or is it because of something else?

Comment: We can ofcourse use a hashmap to contain the values. In fact you have discovered a new attributeset called "javax.print.attribute.HashAttributeSet" which does the same. I am not sure about the reasoning behind AttributeSet though.Need to study.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you give me an example of using Style or MutableAttributeSet in practice? For example when creating a word processor?

Start with the section from the Swing tutorial on [General Text Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) features. It contains a working example that allows you to play with attributes like font, color, italic, bold...