# AttributeSet construction

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to construct a SimpleAttributeSet using the javadoc at 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/SimpleAttributeSet.html

Constructor:

```
SimpleAttributeSet(AttributeSet source)
```

*Creates a new attribute set based on a supplied set of attributes.*

So I need to build an attribute set to put in that constructor.  Looking at the javadoc for that
at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AttributeSet.html
there are no constructors.  All of the methods provided return some information about an attribute set but there is nothing that constructs it or alters it.

So the question is, how is an AttributeSet (and then a SimpleAttributeSet) constructed?

The goal is to have a few fonts defined for use in StyledDocuments, and move all the code defining the fonts into a separate class so the code that uses them is more readable.

in font class:

```
SimpleAttributeSet myFont = new SimpleAttributeSet(myAttributeSet)
```

in target class:

```
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),"myText",myFont);
```

Edited to add:
Goal is something like

```
    public SimpleAttributeSet newFont = new SimpleAttributeSet(
      StyleConstants.setFontFamily("SansSerif"),
      StyleConstants.setFontSize(16)
      );
```

Comment: AttributeSet is an interface but there's a number of classes implementing it, and there are the constructors.

Comment: Yes exactly.  SimpleAttributeSet implements it and provides a constructor, but requires an AttributeSet to be included as a parameter in the constructor.  So the question remains...how to include an AttributeSet in the constructor of the SimpleAttibuteSet?

Comment: There is also a no-argument constructor.

Comment: Yes, but the no argument constructor doesn't allow you to set the attributes needed to define a font.

Comment: Did you search the forum for examples that use a SimpleAttributeSet? I know I've posted examples in the past.

Comment: There are addAttribute methods in the implementing classes.

Comment: @camickr Yes, been working on this issue for a couple hours.  I've looked at many examples such as yours at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430031/what-is-attributeset-and-what-is-it-used-for/23432805#23432805  There are lots of examples that all show modifications of an existing AttributeSet.  None that I can find use a constructor.

Comment: So what's the problem? The `TextComponentDemo` code shows you how to set a Font for a SimpleAttributeSet. Not sure what part of the code you don't understand. It always helps to post the code you have a question about from the tutorial.

Comment: @camickr  The problem is that in the examples they are build in methods, which call methods to define the attributes.  What I'm trying to do is define a set of global fonts that can be used in other classes.  Something like...can't put code in here.  edited the question to show goal.

Comment: I'm lost. All Java code is done in methods. A SimpleAttributeSet is just an object. You create the object, set its properties. Then any JTextPane component can use that attribute set. I have absolutely no idea why you are trying to pass the attributes as parameters. That is not the way that class, or for that matter, most classes work. Normatlly you create an object and then invoke a bunch of setter methods on the object to set its properties.

Comment: I'm trying to create a global constant, which isn't appropriate(allowed?) to call methods on to set it's properties.  They would be in the declaration.

Comment: But yes, I know what you mean.  I can do it that way...already did actually.  I wanted to refactor the definitions out of the method that uses them to make the code shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal is to have a few fonts defined for use in StyledDocuments, and move all the code defining the fonts into a separate class so the code that uses them is more readable.

Maybe something like:

```
public static class DocumentAttributes
{
    private static SimpleAttributeSet font;
    private static SimpleAttributeSet boldFont;

    public static SimpleAttributeSet getFont()
    {
        if (font != null)
            return font;

        font = new SimpleAttributeSet()    
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(font, "SansSerif");
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(font, 16);

        return font;
    }

    public static SimpleAttributeSet getBoldFont()
    {
        if (boldFont != null)
            return boldFont;

        boldfont = new SimpleAttributeSet( getFont() );    
        StyleConstants.setBold(boldFont, true);

        return boldFont;
    }

}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),"myText", DocumentAttributes.getFont());
```

Comment: Brilliant, simple, works.  Thanks!  If they ever have an American Ninja Coder show I'll nominate you. :)